# Display image on scaled size imageView from gallery

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I want to display iamge on imageView from gallery.
When I call picture from gallery, I want to fix size the image as from camera.
Could you give me some your hand?
When I pick from camera, it can be scaled image as createScaledBitmap.
If you have other idea not setImageURI, could you give me advice?
Can I use setImageBitmap instead of URI?
I want to save these picture with related list such as saving into sqlite for blob type.
Please advice me. Thanks.

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
       switch (requestCode)
       {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            selectedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage, 200, 250, false);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            break;

        case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            mImageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        break;
       }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() to fix the size

Comment: do you mean same as PICK_FROM_CAMERA? How do I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in CASE PICK_FROM_GALLERY

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
   selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);

  Bitmap bt=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, false);  

  photo_image.setImageBitmap(bt)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is loading image. Cheers!

Comment: my image is getting streched by using this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap photobitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);


if(photoBitmap!=null)
                            {   
                                // Compressing large image to small one 

                                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 

                                int width = display.getWidth();
                                int height = display.getHeight();


                             int photo_width = photoBitmap.getWidth();
                             int photo_height = photoBitmap.getHeight();

                            if(photo_width >width)
                                photo_width = width;

                           if(photo_height > height)
                                photo_height = height;

                                    photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (photoBitmap, photo_width , photo_height , false);

                                    photo.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);
                             }
```

// If your imageView height and widht are fixed specify them. I have taken device height and width for better understanding.

Comment: imageView id is photo_image, and width and height is 150dp. can you set the fixed size of imageView?

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.photo_image);

Bitmap photobitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);


if(photoBitmap!=null)
                            {   

                             int photo_width = photoBitmap.getWidth();
                             int photo_height = photoBitmap.getHeight();
   //1dp = 1.5 px 150dp = 225px 

                            if(photo_width >225)
                                photo_width = 225;

                           if(photo_height > 225)
                                photo_height = 225;

                                    photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (photoBitmap, photo_width , photo_height , false);

                                    photo.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);
                             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bitmap factory options & resize the scale of the image if you want ..

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8; // your sample size 
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,options);  
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```